# Mangeto 2: Module or API?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I've been tasked with integrating Navision with Magento, I can't decide wether a module would do the job or if it's a better approach to make a web API for this?

I need to achieve several tasks:

- Sync products to Magento from Navision
- Send orders from Magento to Navision
- Fetch product availability from Navision (once a day, and once upon ordering).
- Get customer item prices.
- Get order delivery charges.
- Get the Customer and send the customer to Navision.

And a bunch more.

Now from my understanding I believe I'll need to make a module regardless for certain tasks. But my question is; would the API integration be more ideal? I don't have experience in making an API for Magento before which is why I ask. I know this may be more of a 'whatever suits you' sort of answer, but I'm curious to know how others have gone about this/similar situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use both.

Use native API as much as possible.

Use your custom module to expose custom API if the native one do not suit you.
Use your custom module to send formatted or specific request to Navision based on events or observers.

It is very simple to expose new API in Magento 2.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Kind of thought I'd need to go both ways. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Do not hesitate to ask some clarification about API. If you need to expose some FO data such as image URL, keep in mind that you need to emulate to FO area.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer API way

1. It's from Magento core
2. The input/output format is unique
3. Reduce the chances to get errors and corrupt core data

I have a project on hand using Magento API to retrive data from Magento to mobile apps. Adopting Magento API is simple and reduce the develop time.

I noticed that you added Magento 2 on the tag. For Magento 2 users, in case of you don't know how to use API, you can go to `http://www.example.com/swagger#/` to get the whole API list. Of course some APis need customer or Admin token.

Comment: Thank you, wasn't aware about /swagger# thanks for the heads up. Think I'll go both ways, API & module.